# some c++ include file in Android NDK does not work

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using android JNI to use some c++ code. but how should I cope with the problem of 
The android jni does not recognize the include file in c++ version's some include file:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

so some code of reading file can not use

for example :`istream   ,getline(), string`, how should I find alternate solution?

and some transfer function ,`std::stoull( std::wstring& ), atof, and so on` , 
which are trivial to my module,

Did anyone have similar experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an appropriate C++ runtime to use in your `Application.mk`.

For example:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Quoting from `docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html`:

> To select the runtime you want to use, define `APP_STL` inside your
>   Application.mk to one of the following values:
>   
>       system          -> Use the default minimal system C++ runtime library.
>       gabi++_static   -> Use the GAbi++ runtime as a static library.
>       gabi++_shared   -> Use the GAbi++ runtime as a shared library.
>       stlport_static  -> Use the STLport runtime as a static library.
>       stlport_shared  -> Use the STLport runtime as a shared library.
>       gnustl_static   -> Use the GNU STL as a static library.
>       gnustl_shared   -> Use the GNU STL as a shared library.

The default if you don't specify which one to use is `system`, which only provides the following STL headers:

> cassert cctype cerrno cfloat climits cmath csetjmp csignal
>       cstddef cstdint cstdio cstdlib cstring ctime cwchar new stl_pair.h
>       typeinfo utility

Comment: i have adopted your advice and nearyly solved all problem. but only one leave. the std::strtoull fuction is not recognized. detailed info is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519115/stdstrtoull-not-recognized-under-my-jni-ndk-environment

Comment: Use `strtoull` from `stdlib.h` instead.