# std::strtoull not recognized under my JNI NDK environment

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

i use some c++ code under android project by using JNI.

But always it give an alert saying that :

```
jni/sample.cpp: In function 'int Java_com_android_mymapsforge_create(JNIEnv*, jo
bject)':
jni/sample.cpp:78:14: error: 'strtoull' is not a member of 'std'
jni/sample.cpp:78:14: note: suggested alternative:
C:/TDDOWNLOAD/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729/ndk/android-ndk-r9/platforms/an
droid-14/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h:66:27: note:   'strtoull'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/ann/sample.o] Error 1
```

but however if i include the stdlib.h, it still have the error toast. My android.mk file content is like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ 

LOCAL_MODULE    := libann
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ANN.cpp \
    bd_pr_search.cpp \
    bd_tree.cpp \
    kd_pr_search.cpp \
    kd_split.cpp \
    kd_util.cpp \
    bd_fix_rad_search.cpp \
    bd_search.cpp \
    brute.cpp \
    kd_fix_rad_search.cpp \
    kd_search.cpp \
    kd_tree.cpp \
    kd_dump.cpp \
    perf.cpp\
    sample.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And my Application.mk is like this:

```
# The ARMv7 is significanly faster due to the use of the hardware FPU
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
#APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_OPTIM := release
#APP_OPTIM := debug
#APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

whenever i change the APP_STL flag to stlport_static, stlport_shared, gnustl_shared.

it still have the error toast,

Any have similar problem?

one thing more, my ndk version is **android-ndk-r9**

Comment: Did you `#include <cstdlib>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you including `<cstdlib>`?  The header `<cstdlib>` should declare `std::strtoull`, while `<stdlib.h>` should declare `strtoull` without the `std::`.